# return parent-chain ids of self-reference MSSQL table

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I want to get the parent-chain from a child record. **NOT** ALL the children of a parent or an entire hierarchy.

looking here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql
at point "*F. Using a recursive common table expression to display a hierarchical list*" This is CLOSE to what I want to do but need just the parentage (list of IDs) for a single child row.

Here is my data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Stuff  
    (StuffID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,  
    ParentID int NULL,
    [Name] varchar(25) NOT NULL, 
    [Desc] text NULL)  
GO 

insert dbo.stuff (StuffID, ParentID, [Name], [Desc])
    VALUES (1, null, 'My Home', '1203 WoodHaven Rd')
insert dbo.stuff (StuffID, ParentID, [Name], [Desc])
    VALUES (2, 1, 'Basement', 'Walkout basement')
insert dbo.stuff (StuffID, ParentID, [Name], [Desc])
    VALUES (3, 1, 'Level 1', 'Family room')
insert dbo.stuff (StuffID, ParentID, [Name], [Desc])
    VALUES (4, 1, 'Level 2', 'Living/Kitchen')
insert dbo.stuff (StuffID, ParentID, [Name], [Desc])
    VALUES (5, 1, 'Level 3', 'Bedrooms & Laundry')
insert dbo.stuff (StuffID, ParentID, [Name], [Desc])
    VALUES (6, 1, 'Attic', 'attic space')
insert dbo.stuff (StuffID, ParentID, [Name], [Desc])
    VALUES (7, 2, 'Family Room', 'Family game room')
insert dbo.stuff (StuffID, ParentID, [Name], [Desc])
    VALUES (8, 2, 'Storeroom', 'Storage room')
insert dbo.stuff (StuffID, ParentID, [Name], [Desc])
    VALUES (9, 2, 'Furnace', 'Furnace/Server room')
insert dbo.stuff (StuffID, ParentID, [Name], [Desc])
    VALUES (10, 7, 'Closet', 'Under stairs junk closet')
insert dbo.stuff (StuffID, ParentID, [Name], [Desc])
    VALUES (11, 9, 'Furnace floor', 'Furnace Room Floor (under desk)')
insert dbo.stuff (StuffID, ParentID, [Name], [Desc])
    VALUES (12, 9, 'Furnace keyboard Shelf', 'Furnace room name desk shelf')
insert dbo.stuff (StuffID, ParentID, [Name], [Desc])
    VALUES (13, 9, 'Furnace High Shelf', 'Furnace/Server room high shelf')
insert dbo.stuff (StuffID, ParentID, [Name], [Desc])
    VALUES (14, 13, 'Router', 'ASUS AC router')
insert dbo.stuff (StuffID, ParentID, [Name], [Desc])
    VALUES (15, 13, 'Deprecated server', 'Old WinServer')
```

I want to know where the 'Router' is.  The result I expect is:
    1
    2
    9
    13
    14
and I would probably search for it by partial name:
    WHERE [Name] LIKE '%rout%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;with parents as
(
    select 
        StuffID, ParentID
    from 
        [Stuff]
    WHERE 
        [Name] LIKE '%rout%'
    union all
    select
        s.StuffID, s.ParentID
    from
        [Stuff] s
    join parents p on
        s.StuffID = p.ParentID
)
SELECT 
    StuffID 
from 
    parents
order by 
    StuffID
```

The output will be: 1 2 7 13 14 (differs from your expectation 1 2 9 13 14, is that a mistake?)

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I wanted. And yes, I have a problem in my data parentage (which I fixed in my example).